Secret door in shed has fantasy world behind it
I'm looking for the title of a movie I recently watched, maybe 2 months ago. I saw the preview online during an ad I had to watch. Man's father dies and he finds a secret door in his father's shed/garage? And I remember when he falls in it is like a fantasy world with "fun" different creatures. Reminded me of Big Fish. I know the main character is famous from what I think was a TV show a few years back but cannot find him online to know his name to find the movie. 

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions you can give?

You saw the whole movie or just the preview? "I saw the preview online during an ad I had to watch."

I just found out what movie you are looking for and it is not Tomorrowland. The movie you are looking for is called "What Lives Inside" with Colin Hanks (though it's a mini-series).

While mourning the loss of his world-famous puppeteer father, Taylor finds himself mysteriously transported to the magical world of his father's show. 




Hope this helps.

Sounds like it might be Tomorrowland, a movie that's just come out with George Clooney as a major character.
Although I think the other major character is a young woman not a man, it has some of the major themes you describe, and George Clooney is certainly famous for a TV show a few years back.

Downvoter care to share either a comment or an alternative answer?

Tomorrowland seems an unlikely candidate.  Time-wise, the movie was released May 22, which would've only been 8 days before--rather than 2 months per the OP's--post.  Plot-wise, not much matches up: the protagonist is a young woman (as you state), and the young woman's father survives the entire film.  The OP suggests that the fantasy world is accessible through a door, where in Tomorrowland access is through  either a spaceship or magical elevator.  Also, there are no 'fun', different creatures--TL is populated with basically humans.
